# How to Index a UITable with no sections at all

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, indexing

It is possible (or imposible) to index a table without any sections?

Comment: You could return swap the return of `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and use `[indexPath.section]` instead of `indexPath.row` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can, nothing has changed in swift other than the syntax:

```
/* section headers
   appear above each `UITableView` section */
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
    -> String {
    // do not display empty `Section`s
    if !self.sections[section].users.isEmpty {
        return self.collation.sectionTitles[section] as String
    }
    return ""
}

/* section index titles
   displayed to the right of the `UITableView` */
override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView)
    -> [AnyObject] {
    return self.collation.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
    atIndex index: Int)
    -> Int {
    return self.collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
}
```

[Full example here](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing/).